# Postgres rank() without duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm ranking race data for series of cycling events. Racers win various amounts of points for their position in races. I want to retain the discrete event scoring, but also rank the racer in the series. For example, considering a sub-query that returns this:

| License # | Rider Name | Total Points | Race Points | Race ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Joe | 25 | 5 | 567 |
| 123 | Joe | 25 | 12 | 234 |
| 123 | Joe | 25 | 8 | 987 |
| 456 | Ahmed | 20 | 12 | 567 |
| 456 | Ahmed | 20 | 8 | 234 |

You can see Joe has 25 points, as he won 5, 12, and 8 points in three races. Ahmed has 20 points, as he won 12 and 8 points in two races.

Now for the ranking, what I'd like is:

| Place | License # | Rider Name | Total Points | Race Points | Race ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Joe | 25 | 5 | 567 |
| 1 | 123 | Joe | 25 | 12 | 234 |
| 1 | 123 | Joe | 25 | 8 | 987 |
| 2 | 456 | Ahmed | 20 | 12 | 567 |
| 2 | 456 | Ahmed | 20 | 8 | 234 |

But if I use `rank()` and `order by "Total Points"`, I get:

| Place | License # | Rider Name | Total Points | Race Points | Race ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Joe | 25 | 5 | 567 |
| 1 | 123 | Joe | 25 | 12 | 234 |
| 1 | 123 | Joe | 25 | 8 | 987 |
| 4 | 456 | Ahmed | 20 | 12 | 567 |
| 4 | 456 | Ahmed | 20 | 8 | 234 |

Which makes sense, since there are three "ties" at 25 points.

`dense_rank()` solves this problem, but if there are legitimate ties across different racers, I want there to be gaps in the rank (e.g if Joe and Ahmed both had 25 points, the next racer would be in third place, not second).

The easiest way to solve this I think would be to issue two queries, one with the "duplicate" racers eliminated, and then a second one where I can retain the individual race data, which I need for the points break down display.

I can also probably, given enough effort, think of a way to do this in a single query, but I'm wondering if I'm not just missing something really obvious that could accomplish this in a single, relatively simple query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using the `RANK` window function >> https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-rank-function/. It should give exactly what you're looking for. For better troubleshooting with your query, update your post with the query and provide input sample data.

Comment: "... the next racer would be in third place, not second..." -- If they are tied, which one is the **third place** and which one is the **second place**? You are describing a situation where they are not actually in a tie. If you untie them, for example, by sorting them by name, then the solution is quite simple: `DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY total_points DESC, rider_name)`.

Comment: Please peovide a clear description without "I think" and "I can try".  Currently one can only guess what your desired output is (and what you tried, how you tried it what was not correct about that try, etc, etc)

Comment: @TheImpaler if the top two racers have 25 points, they are tied for first. The next racer, say they have 20 points, is in third place, since there are two racers ahead of them. In this case there is no second place position. But maybe this is the wrong approach, maybe I should just stick with `dense_rank()`, which is what I'm using now. I'll take a look at what some other points series do.

Comment: I actually see examples done both ways. So maybe I'm just over thinking this whole thing.

Comment: @Luuk haven't tried anything yet. I didn't want to spend all afternoon on coming up with something complicated if there's an easy approach, thus the goal of the question. I'm not a DBA, so I'm trying to avoid overcomplicating this.

No need to guess what my desired output is. I gave an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to break this into steps to get what you want, but that can be done in a single query with common table expressions:

```
with riders as (      -- get individual riders
  select distinct license, rider, total_points
    from racists
), places as (        -- calculate non-dense rankings
  select license, rider, rank() over (order by total_points desc) as place
    from riders
)
select p.place, r.*   -- join rankings into main table
  from places p
       join racists r on (r.license, r.rider) = (p.license, p.rider);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=391ee570c8579f6e1d343266e6bec14e)*

Comment: I... I don't think `racists` is the table name you're looking for. Maybe `racers`?

Comment: I figured it'd involve common table expressions, but was a bit intimidated. Thanks for the help, this worked great.